# Informal phrase violating Grammar

Tags: grammaticality

There is the phrase that could be spoken to one mate:

> I have been worried about you.

This is the pattern of Present Perfect Passive Voice i.e. have+been+V3. It means that it should be passive construction, but It's not by the sense (I was worrying, I had been worrying). As e.g. in the next sentence:

> At the conference I have been asked about my work a lot.

Here, this is the really passive construction (Others had been asking me about my work).

But why the first sentence is not grammatical?

Comment: Are you asking why it doesn't parallel, say, "It has been taken from the table", with corresponding words I-It, worried-taken, you-table? That is, one can construct an active voice "He took it from the table", but not an (equivalent sense) active voice *"He worried me about you"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper use of passive and active voices?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131230/proper-use-of-passive-and-active-voices) and others.

Comment: Or possibly of ['He is loved': is 'loved' an adjective or a verb here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166689/he-is-loved-is-loved-an-adjective-or-a-verb/166694#166694). 'But why the first sentence is not in the Grammar frames?' has me beaten.

Comment: The first sentence is not a passive construction. It is the present perfect active. Hint: try adding an agent to it, such as *by John* (you get the truly ungrammatical 'I have been worried about you by John'). So one really doesnt understand your question.

Comment: _Worried_, like _tired_, is an experiential adjective formed from the past participle of a verb. This does not make it a verb, and it does not make a clause like _I am tired_ a passive clause; it's just a predicate adjective.

Answer (score 1):

Language is not all about grammar, semantics play a big part too.

A sentence like this:

> I was worried about you.

You could grammatically try to parse as a passive construction, parallel to, say

> I was asked about my work.

However, that second sentence can be easily reread as an active construction:

> (Someone) asked me about my work.

Whereas the original sentence struggles a bit:

> (Something) worried me about you.

Nothing is really off, though.

Now, let's compare the original sentence to a different construction:

> I was happy for you.

Here, *happy* can *not* be parsed as a verb in any way, and we are simply looking at a subject+(past copula)+adjective. If we interpret the first sentence in the same way, we can see the obvious parallel:

> I | was | worried | about you.
>   I | was | happy | for you.

Grammatically we can parse the sentence as a passive construction, or as an active construction where *worried* functions attributively ("like an adjective"). Semantically, I think the sentence is usually parsed as the latter, active, construction.