# desired vs. desirable

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

I have written a paper and the reviewer said me that I must change "a more desired solution" to "a more desirable solution". I am not sure about the differences. I have also some similar usages of this combination. It would be grateful if you could suggest me which one is more applicable.

N.B: I have a number of solutions (points) that the data publisher checks them and selects one of them, or in another scenario, she first states her preferences, and our algorithm finds the best one for his.

Similar usages:

1. ... or even direct the method toward a desired point.
2. He checks it with different parameters to attain a desired trade-off between A and B.
3. ... which usually results in an  undesired quality degradation of published data.
4. with the possibility to direct the anonymization process toward a more desired trade-off point.
5. it to reach a desirable trade-off point.
6. results in the desired partitioning.
7. After applying X, the desired partitioning is produced.
8. ...explicit expression of the desired values of the objective functions makes the algorithm more effective.
9. It can converge toward the desired point in an effective manner.
10. ...to achieve a desirable trade-off point.
11. ...that usually results in an undesired decrease of information utility.
12. ... and capture some undesired information.
13. ... to reach a desired point.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130824/should-i-use-desirable-or-desired-here

Comment: Please see [ell.se]

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It is sometimes really hard to find the correct forum for a question, I think.

Comment: It *could* be a matter of how you ask the question. If you ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage) first, people there will be able to advise; or maybe suggest a better SE site. If there's not much going on, it may take a little while to get an answer posted, but we usually try to be helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first sense given by [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/desirable) for *desirable* is:

> adj. 1. Worth having or seeking, as by being useful, advantageous, or
>   pleasing: a desirable job in the film industry; a home computer with
>   many desirable features.

Notice that there does not even need to be anyone actually desiring say a job in films or bells and whistles on their computer for this adjective to be an option (though someone must be doing the assessment that the object is 'worth having').

The participial adjective *desired* implies that someone (or a sentient agent, at least) is desiring the object / outcome / ....

Here, both "a more desired solution" and "a more desirable solution" make sense. The first at least hints towards 'a better / more favoured one of the various possible solutions [we're considering]' whereas the second, which is almost certainly intended here, means 'a better solution [than the one just mentioned]'.

............

1. *... or even direct the method toward a desired point.* ('point' is seen or 'seen' (ie in mind); 'desired' correct)
2. *He checks it with different parameters to attain a desired trade-off between A and B.* (the trade-off desired is again in 'his' mind, at least fairly clearly envisioned: 'desired' correct)

3 *.... which usually results in an undesired quality degradation of published data.* (undesired = unwanted here; I think using either option is nigh-on tautologous anyway) (as with 11)

.4. *with the possibility to direct the anonymization process toward a more desired trade-off point.*  (I'd use desirable here) (as in 5)

.6. this is the partitioning (or the sort of partitioning) we wished for: desired. as with 7.

I'll just go on to contrast 12 and 12b:

> 12 *... and capture some undesired information.* probable reading: We do not want the
>   information to be captured. (though may mean same as 12b)
>
> 12b *... and capture some undesirable information.* We do not want
>   this particular information to be captured. This information is inherently undesirable.

Comment: Please let me know about some of my examples above...

Answer (score 1):

*Desired* can take an extra argument phrase which *desirable* can't:

> That cake is desired by them.
>
> *That cake is desirable by them.

If you don't specify who desires the cake *desired* leaves you asking "by who?" Whereas *desirable* suggests that the desirability would be agreed upon generally by everyone involved.

> That cake is desired. [By who??]
>
> That cake is desirable. [Everyone knows it's true.]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the tense of the words. "Desired" is past tense. While "desirable" is future tense. The suffix "ed" often denotes past tense (though obviously not strictly always depending on the root of the word). So speaking about future desires you would talk about the "desirable" effects of your plan. But saying that an implementation of a certain action plan "X" that didn't have the "desired" effects, indicates a past tense.

Though I suppose you could get away with saying the "desired" effect in future tense if you're looking for poetic license. But you'd have to set it up right by saying you have "desired" something for a long time, so you will implement action "X" to fulfill that.

In the end it depends, as with most language, what you are ultimately trying to convey to your audience. However poetic license is often not sought after when working on business communications, where things are quite formal. And in that case "a more desirable solution" is the correct phrasing.

Here's the reference for the "ed" suffix:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ed

Here's the reference for the "able" suffix:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-able?s=t

Comment: I want it for my technical paper (in computer science). would you please say your idea about the above examples?

Comment: This information is incorrect. Desired is not necessarily past tense ("wisdom is a virtue to be desired above all others"), nor is desirable necessarily the future tense ("being a trader was a highly desirable profession until the recession").

Comment: @medica As I said above, you can work "desired" into a future tense, but it is more poetic than technical. The future tense in your first example is denoted by saying "to be" before "desired". And the past tense in your second example was accounted for in "was ... desirable". Saying "was desired" is redundant because of the "ed" suffix.

Comment: Nope. Can't agree. Not even with your third faulty assumption that *was desired* is redundant; it is merely the passive voice. "Beauty was desired above ability by studio executives." You should really try to support your answers with source material if you don't have a grasp of the language.

Comment: You don't have to resort to insults when you disagree. And I plainly referenced the both the "ed" and "able" suffixes. I may not have a wealth of quotes as you seem to, but I know my word roots fairly well. And just because someone somewhere used a word that way doesn't make it correct.

Comment: I can't find a single comment made by medica that I would class as an 'insult' here. She corrects far more sensitively than I usually do. And she's correct in her statements (I think you're after "'desired' implies that some desiring has been and is going on' rather than 'desired is {implication [always an indicator of]} past tense'.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as loved and loveable. Desired indicates a status, while desirable indicates a possible status. As soon as you use desired in a future tense along with the words "would", "will", it begins to make no sense. Because referring to a current status that has not yet come into fruition is impossible. It wouldn't be current.

"A more desired solution WAS once available." - Makes perfect sense.

"A more desired solution WILL be put in place." - Doesn't.

I'm guessing you implemented the latter by mistake. Or something very similar like:

"This would be a more desired solution."

Answer (score -2):

The *desirable* option, ending with 'able', has a 'susceptible of, tending to' nuance to it that makes it slightly less fit to a cold computer science paper.

[Reference for the able suffix](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-able?s=t) borrowed from user2801537